# Split master excel into multiple files based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro to split my excel file into multiple file based on date range.

I have a excel file with following data and many other similar data

```
Name       date_of_birth
A          10-01-2014
B          10-02-2014
C          10-03-2014
D          10-04-2014
E          10-05-2014
F          10-06-2014
G          10-07-2014
H          10-08-2014
I          10-09-2014
J          10-10-2014
K          10-11-2014
L          10-12-2014
```

I need to split the data into multiple file with each file containing data for 4 months. Could you please help me with this.
 
Final files should be like:

first.xls

```
Name    date_of_birth
A       10-01-2014
B       10-02-2014
C       10-03-2014
D       10-04-2014
```

second.xls

```
Name    date_of_birth
E       10-05-2014
F       10-06-2014
G       10-07-2014
H       10-08-2014
```

third.xls

```
Name    date_of_birth
I       10-09-2014
J       10-10-2014
K       10-11-2014
L       10-12-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub newfile()

```
'Naming the master workbook
Set m = ThisWorkbook

'Creating a new workbook
Set first = Workbooks.Add
    With first
        .Title = "first"
        .Subject = "firs1t"
        .SaveAs Filename:="first.xls"
    End With

'Naming the created workbook for use in macro
Set f = Workbooks("first")

'Naming a worksheet in master
Set wsm = m.Sheets("master")

'lastrow in master excel
lastrow = wsm.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'finding the month from the date
'Dim month As Integer

Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = f.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
WS.Name = "first"

c = 2
For i = 2 To lastrow
m = month(wsm.Cells(i, 2))

    If m >= 1 And m <= 4 Then
    WS.Cells(c, 1) = wsm.Cells(i, 1)
    WS.Cells(c, 2) = wsm.Cells(i, 2)
    c = c + 1
    End If

Next i

f.Close
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Sub test1()

'Naming the master workbook

Set m = ThisWorkbook

'Creating a new workbook

Set first = Workbooks.Add

```
With first

    .title = "first"

    .Subject = "first"

    .SaveAs Filename:="first.xls"

End With
```

'Naming the created workbook for use in macro

Set f = Workbooks("first")

'Naming a worksheet in master

Set wsm = ThisWorkbook

'lastrow in master excel

lastrow = wsm.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & _

```
      wsm.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

'finding the month from the date

Dim mo As Integer

Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = f.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))

WS.Name = "first"

c = 2

For i = 2 To lastrow

m = 1

```
If m >= 1 And m <= 4 Then

WS.Cells(c, 1) = wsm.Cells(i, 1)

WS.Cells(c, 2) = wsm.Cells(i, 2)

c = c + 1

End If
```

Next i

f.Close

End Sub

but still the If condition to check if m>1 and m<4 does not work